# While loop not working properly with scanner

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Input:
2
Insert
5 23
Delete
0

Code:

```
int q = scan.nextInt();
while (q-- > 0) {

    String s = scan.next();
    if (s.equals("Delete")) {
        list.remove(scan.nextInt());
    } else {
        list.add(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Output:

Need to perform both insert and delete operations on a list, but it is performing the first operation and exiting loop without performing the second operation.

Please help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: Try a debugger. Try printing `s`.

Comment: I tried, it is reading string 'Insert' or 'Delete' properly. Problem is, while loop is executing only once, it is not executing for the second time irrespective of the q value.

Comment: Got the answer, thanks for the response.